# Update only Date portion of DateTime

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008. 
I have a datetime in the database
where the value is

```
    10/4/2012 8:03:00 AM
```

How do I update only the date portion?

The field name is dTime.

I like to update the date to 10/5/2012 and keep the time as it is.

Comment: What type of update do you wanna do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    DTColumn DATETIME NOT NULL
);
GO
INSERT dbo.MyTable(DTColumn) VALUES 
('20120410 08:03:00.000'),
('20010101 01:01:01.000');

BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    UPDATE  dbo.MyTable
    -- Style 126 / ISO8601 = yyyy-mm-ddThh:mi:ss.mmm        
    SET     DTColumn = STUFF(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),DTColumn,126) ,1, 10, '2012-05-10') 
    -- Uncomment this line to see the old and new values
    -- OUTPUT   deleted.DTColumn AS OldValue, inserted.DTColumn AS NewValue
    WHERE   CONVERT(DATE,DTColumn)='2012-04-10' 

    SELECT * FROM dbo.MyTable;
ROLLBACK;
-- COMMIT
```

Results:

```
OldValue                NewValue
----------------------- -----------------------
2012-04-10 08:03:00.000 2012-05-10 08:03:00.000

ID          DTColumn
----------- -----------------------
1           2012-05-10 08:03:00.000
2           2001-01-01 01:01:01.000
```

Comment: nice use of inserted and deleted tables.

Answer (score 38):

```
UPDATE
    tableX
SET
    columnX = DATEADD( day, DATEDIFF( day, columnX, '20120510' ), columnX ) 
WHERE
    (conditionX) ;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET YourColumn = DATEADD(MONTH,1,YourColumn) 
WHERE YourColumn = '20120410 08:03:00'
```

I assumed that you posted your date on `DD/MM/YYYY` format. If it was `MM/DD/YYYY` you should use `DATEADD(DAY,1,YourColumn)` instead.

Comment: hey, do you mean the first parameter afftected by date format? I think the document says it represent the part of date, and we don't need to care about date format. `DATEADD(MONTH, 1, YourColumn)` add a month to the date, but `DATEADD(DAY, 1, YourColumn)` only add 1 day to the date.

Answer (score 1):

```
 UPDATE table1 
 SET columnDatetime = '10/5/2012' + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar(12), CONVERT(time, columnDatetime))
 WHERE CONVERT(date, columnDatetime) = '10/4/2012'
```

Just use varchar and modify what you want in it without touch the time.
In this example I use CONVERT(varchar(12), columnDatetime) to get a string with length of 12 characteres assuming a case of time with a format for example like "20:10:15.250".

Answer (score 0):

update tableX set dttime = CONCAT("2012-10-24 ",time(dttime))  WHERE date(dt1)='2012-05-10'

Comment: Awww... That poor little piece of code. It looks so scared that people might not like it, so alone and vulnerable. Wouldn't you like to give it some company and protection by adding an explanation? (And maybe some improved formatting...) Please read [answer].

Answer (score 0):

Here is my query. It will update signout date with signing date without changing the time.

UPDATE TableName
SET
SignInTime=STUFF(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),SignInTime,126) ,1, 10, CONVERT(date, SignOutTime))
where Id = 100